# ZF2 User\Module.php cannot call $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm learning ZF2 by starting write a simple UserAuth Plugin for authentication but have got the exceptions:
An exception was raised while creating "userAuth"; no instance returned
Previous exceptions:
The supplied or instantiated driver object does not implement Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\DriverInterface

error at this line: $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')

The following is my User\Module.php

class Module {

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
}

public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
        ),
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}

public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}

public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
        ),
        'factories' => array(
            'User\Form\Signin' => function($sm) {
                $form = new Form\Signin();
                $form->setInputFilter(new Form\SigninFilter);
                return $form;
            },
            'User\Auth\Service' => function ($sm) {
                return new \Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService(
                    new \Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session(),
                    new \Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable($sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'))
                );
            },
        ),
    );
}

public function getControllerPluginConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'UserAuth' => function ($sm) {
                $sl = $sm->getServiceLocator();
                $authService = $sl->get('User\Auth\Service');
                $authAdapter = new \Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable($sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'));
                $controllerPlugin = new Controller\Plugin\UserAuth();
                $controllerPlugin->setAuthService($authService);
                $controllerPlugin->setAuthAdapter($authAdapter);
                return $controllerPlugin;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

}

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Did you actually read the docs of `ZfcUser`? There's a section about this specific part at https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser#post-install-zenddb

Comment: yes, i have db config in autoload/local.php

Comment: and also a configured factory/service?

Comment: global.php return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);

Comment: $authAdapter = new \Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable($sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')); should be $authAdapter = new \Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable($sl->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'));

Comment: exactly! you save me a day! thank for all helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
```

to the top of Controller\Plugin\UserAuth.php

and:

```
extends Adapter
```

after:

```
class UserAuth
```

in the same file. That will at least get you going in the right direction.